# How Often Will Java Sync To Main Memory?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a set of counters which will only ever be updated in a single thread.

If I read these values from another thread and I don't user volatile/atomic/synchronized how out of date can these values be?

I ask as I am wondering if I can avoid using volatile/atomic/synchronized here.

I currently believe that I can't make any assumptions about time to update (so I am forced to use at least volatile). Just want to make sure I am not missing something here.

Comment: As out of date as they need to be to screw you over. Seriously. Don't play such games. Just do it properly.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using those keywords?

Comment: I couldn't +1 delnans comment above enough. As far as I know, without any synchronisation primitive, the changes to the value are not guaranteed to be visible to any other thread, ever.

Comment: Unnecessary overhead. If I don't need to synchronize I would like to avoid it (which I would usually do by default in this scenario). I am not "playing games".

Comment: Again, I don't care if I read the current value in the other thread, only that the value is relatively recent.

Comment: @Gareth The times you would have needed to worry about "overhead" like a volatile keywoard (not that it existed back then) are like what, 30 years past? That's ridiculous to call that unnecessary overhead when you are operating with multiple threads in this day and age.

Comment: Re-read delnan's comment. How out of date can you tolerate your values in the worst case? Now add one second to that, and that's how out-of-date the values will be. Count on it.

Comment: The only guarantee you have is that if thread A writes something that is read later by B and the write and read are properly synchronized (using synchronized, volatile, or any concurrent collection), then everything that has been written before this write by A will be visible from B. So if you regularly synchronize the threads for another shared state, then you'll at least see the last change made to the counter before this synchronization. But this really sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: Even if you just care for a recent value you could end up reading corrupted values if your values are long or double.

Comment: An easy fix is to make the real counter an atomic value. Then write into it every 256 iterations (or however many) of a per-thread counter. In this way you get speed *and* correct operation.

Comment: @ZanLynx - that is what I was thinking (if this was really important). I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something here.

Comment: Not appreciating the tone of some of the comments here. I am not asking for a judgement, just an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way that I can avoid the synchronization of these variables is to do the following (similar to what Zan Lynx suggested in the comments):

1. Figure out the maximum age I am prepared to accept. I will make this
   the "update interval".
2. Each "update interval" copy the unsynchronized counter variables to synchronized   variables. This neeeds to be done on the write thread.
3. Read thread(s) can only read from these synchronized variables.

Of course, this optimization may only be a marginal improvement and would probably not be worth it considering the extra complexity it would create.

Comment: Also note that [the cost of volatile read is benign](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2005-October/002024.html) on recent infrastructures (although a volatile write is a little more expensive). So you could read from a volatile variable all the time, but write to the volatile variable only every x seconds and use a normal variable the rest of the time.

Answer (score 4):

How stale a value can get is left entirely to the discretion of the implementation -- the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) doesn't provide any guarantees. You will be writing code that depends on the implementation details of a particular JVM and which can be broken by changes to memory models or to how the JIT reorders code. The spec seems to be written with the intent of giving the implementers as much rope as they want, as long as they observe the constraints imposed by volatile, final, synchronized, etc.

Comment: .... or simply by the next update, where the JIT makes a slightly different decision here and there

Comment: Thanks for the spec reference (+1). Of course I wouldn't want to write something which was JVM dependent.

Answer (score 4):

> I ask as I am wondering if I can avoid using volatile/atomic/synchronized here.

In practice, the CPU cache is probably going to be synchronized to main memory anyway on a regular basis (how often depends on many parameters), so  it sounds like you would be able to see some new values from time to time.

But that is missing the point: the actual problem is that if you don't use a proper synchronization pattern, the compiler is free to "optimise" your code and remove the update part.

For example:

```
class Broken {
    boolean stop = false;

    void broken() throws Exception {
        while (!stop) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is authorised to rewrite that code as:

```
void broken() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

because there is no obligation to check if the non-volatile `stop` might change while you are executing the `broken` method. Mark the `stop` variable as `volatile` and that optimisation is not allowed any more.

Bottom line: if you need to share state you need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Java8 has a new class called LongAdder which helps with the problem of using volatile on a field. But until then...

If you do not use volatile on your counter then the results are unpredictable. If you do use volatile then there are performance problems since each write must guarantee cache/memory coherency. This is a huge performance problem when there are many threads writing frequently.

For statistics and counters that are not critical to the application, I give users the option of volatile/atomic or none with none the default. So far, most use none.